# Bumping Groovy version in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

My project is giving me an "Illegal Reflective" warning, which seems to be a problem before Groovy v3.0. However, Gradle on my machine is running Groovy v2.5.4 and I can't seem to bump this to > 3.0. I've tried having "`compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.2'`" in my dependencies but this doesn't do anything.

How can I bump the version of Groovy that Gradle uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle has an internal Groovy it uses to run Gradle itself. Declaring a compile dependency on Groovy will not change that. To change the internal Groovy version the only way I know is to go to the lib directory of your installed Gradle and replace the groovy jars in there.

But I advise against doing that. You may see side effects. Groovy 3 contains breaking changes and I do not know if they impact Gradle. Some of them impacted Grails, which is why we already have 3.0.2 despite 3.0 being quite new.

The "Illegal Reflective" warning is just that, a warning. It is only there to try to force library makers to quit doing what they (the makers of the Java API) declared as wrong and warn they will enforce it at some point. But JDK11 is not yet that point.

Comment: Interesting why they don't update Groovy even within the same 2.5.X releases? The latest now is 2.5.13, released about a month ago but even nightly build of the next Gradle 6.7 uses Groovy 2.5.12. Why? Take a look at the list of fixed bugs and improvements: http://groovy-lang.org/changelogs/changelog-2.5.13.html

Comment: @RostislavKrasny most likely something changed in Groovy that the don't want and don't care to put this enough to our attention or work around it. And we do not have anyone involved enough on the Gradle side to kick off things that way either