# Java 14 support in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

All groovyconsole binary distros I have found don't support Java 14. The console complains if you try to specify a Jar file that has been compiled with Java 14, for example.

The obvious solution, I thought, was to build Groovy with Java 14. That seems non-trivial.

1. gradle.wrapper.properties files contain

distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip

which is a broken URL. Change that to https and then it works, partially.

2. You then get

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine java version from '14.0.2'.

Reading the docs for gradle makes it clear that most (all?) versions of gradle do not support Java 14. Definitely version 2.3 does not. Why - I have no idea.

So... back to my original question. How can I get a groovy installation to support Java 14?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the Jar cannot be loaded, it is most likely the asm lib, which is unable to read it. To read Java14 you need at least ASM 7.2 I think. ASM in Groovy is not provided as standalone library, because of possible conflicts with other jar dependencies it is shadowed (bytecode is transformed by renaming the packages and directly added to the Groovy jar). I see here 2 options:

- compile Groovy yourself and change the dependencies to have at least ASM 7.2. It does not matter if you build Groovy with a lower version of the JDK, the JDK still allows to read "old" jars.
- use at least Groovy 2.5.9, 3.0.0 or 2.4.19, as they include asm 7.2 or higher

Of course this does not mean it will change the Groovy Gradle is using easily. For that I would use Groovy 2.5 and read [Bumping Groovy version in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60654107/bumping-groovy-version-in-gradle/60654493#60654493)

If this does not solve the problem or answer the question I would need more details.